# How To Count The Number of Words Stored in A Double Pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I want to count the number of words that are in a file. I store each line of the text in the file using a double pointer and then manipulate it do other things.

```
char **create2DArray()
{
    int i = 0;

    char **str = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 100);

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        str[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000);
    }
    return str;
}

char **readFile(char **str)
{
    int i = 0;
    FILE *pFile;
    char *filename = "C:\\Users\\muham\\OneDrive\\Documents\\A2\\A2 Samples\\sample1.txt";

pFile = fopen(filename, "r");

if (pFile == NULL)
{
    printf("Could not open file");
    exit(1);
}

while (fgets(str[i], 1000, pFile) != NULL)
{
    RemoveReturn(str[i]);
    lineCount++;
    printf("%s\n", str[i]);
    i++;
}
fclose(pFile);
return str;
}
int wordCount(char **str)
{
    int wordCounting = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int q = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < lineCount; i++)
    {
        for (q = 0; q <= strlen(str[i]); q++)
        {
            if (*str[q] == ' ' || *str[q] == '\0')
            {
                wordCounting++;
            }
            if (*str[q] == ' ' && *str[q + 1] == ' ' && *str[0] != ' ')
            {
                wordCounting--;
            }
            if (*str[0] == ' ')
            {
                wordCounting--;
            }
            if (*str[q] == ' ' && *str[q + 1] == '\0')
            {
                wordCounting--;
            }
            if (strlen(str[q]) == 0)
            {
                wordCounting--;
            }
            }
    }
printf("%d\n", wordCounting);
return wordCounting;
}
```

As of right now, when I run the program, wordCount prints 0. Why is this happening? Is it because I am iterating through the number of pointers with str[i] and not the strings stored in str[i]? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code; The most obvious one is probably your loop `for (i = 0; i <= strlen(str[i]); i++)`, in which you compare the length of the `i`th string with the value of `i`, and you use the same `i` then to access the characters of the `i`th string. This all rarely makes sense.

I'd start with two things:

First, make sure that you do not access uninitialized rows, i.e. consider `lineCount`. A simple way would be to make it either a global variable or to return it in `readFile`; signature would change to `int readFile(char **str) { ....; return lineCount; }`

Second, use two nested loops:

```
for (int line=0; line<lineCount; line++) {
   for (int column=0; column < strlen(str[line]); column++) {
     // your code for detecting lines goes here...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, I don't why I didn't see that, I updated the code to match what you were saying